# Replace previous when match regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, csv, sed, awk

I need to delete the "end of line" of the previous line when current line starts is not a number ^[!0-9], basically if match, append to the line before, I'm a sed & awk n00b, and really like them btw. thanks

***edit:***

$ cat file

```
1;1;1;text,1
2;4;;8;some;1;1;1;more
100;tex
t
broke

4564;1;1;"also
";12,2121;546465
```

$ "script" file

```
1;1;1;text,1
2;4;;8;some;1;1;1;more
100;text broke 
4564;1;1;"also";12,2121;546465
```

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer at the moment but basically you just need to keep the last line in a variable until you see the next line and then decide what to do with it. Either print it alone or print it with the current line. Then you need to make sure to print the last line when your input is all done (an `END` block in awk or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post any sample input or expected output so this is a guess but it sounds like what you're asking for:

```
$ cat file
a
b
3
4
c
d
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",(NR>1 && /^[[:digit:]]/ ? ORS : ""),$0} END{print ""}' file
ab
3
4cd
```

On the OPs newly posted input:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",(NR>1 && /^[[:digit:]]/ ? ORS : ""),$0} END{print ""}' file
1;1;1;text,1
2;4;;8;some;1;1;1;more
100;textbroke
4564;1;1;"also";12,2121;546465
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant every line should start with numbers, so i guess i should run your answer as many times is needed, Does this works if start with ^\n|^\$ ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you're asking. Update your original question to include some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please excuse my english also, is not my first language, I hope is more clear now, Thanks for your help Ed!

Comment: Did you try my script? It produces exactly the output you say you want given the input your posted except for `textbroke` instead of `text broke` but you haven't told us a rule that we could use to do that yet.

Comment: is runing, theres like 2.5 million rows, takes like ~5min, not all lines have the same amount/type of fields btw

Comment: That's very surprising. I'd expect it to take a few seconds. You sure you're doing exactly what I posted? Amount and type of fields are irrelevant - the scripts not looking at fields. I just tried it on a file of 8 million lines and it took 13 seconds.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake, sorry, apparently worked fine, there's no output when **$grep -v "^[!0-9]" file**, should I mark your anwser as successfull? or check the whole file first? takes me like 20 mins, I really appreciate your help Ed Morton!

Comment: If I were you I'd come up with a test case input file that contains the edge cases you think might be difficult to handle and run the tool on that and check that the output matches expectations but it's entirely up to you. The script WILL do what I THINK you want but if there's something you haven't told us about yet (e.g. why there should be a space between `text` and `broke` in your posted desired output) then it probably won't do what you want.

Comment: If the line starts with **-** doesn't append the line to the previous line

Comment: Yes, it does. There's nothing in the script that treats `-` any differently from any other non-digit.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, before your script  **$grep -v "^[!0-9]" file** I get output, after your script theres no output, but in the text editor (SciTe) i can see the lines starting with non-digits, I know it sounds stupid but is true, and yes I'm saving the output into a new file Ed'sScript>newfile, I'll check everyting again and let you know later

Comment: Maybe your original file was created by Windows and so has spurious control-Ms atthe ends of lines messing things up. Run dos2unix on the file then try again.

Comment: I guess my PC was tire last night, Thank you for the solution.

Comment: I copied the text into a new file, just in case, then it worked, but it was just a guess, didn't see the dos2unix post, I'll use it next time.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/\n([^0-9]|$)/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Keep two lines in the pattern space and if the start of the second line is empty or does not start with an integer, remove the newline.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby on your system

```
  array = File.open("file").readlines
  array.each_with_index do |val,ind|  
    array[ind-1].chomp! if not val[/^\d/]    # just chomp off the previous item's \n
  end
  puts array.join
```

output

```
# ruby test.rb 
1;1;1;text,1
2;4;;8;some;1;1;1;more
100;textbroke
4564;1;1;"also";12,2121;546465
```